# 2 userids in 1 application

Tags: mysql, database-design, join

I have this `user` table and `application` table. Now in 1 application there are two users to be able to access that application. One is the applicant and the other is the approving officer.

How would I design the relationship between those so that when I transact both id's will show up in application

```
CREATE TABLE user(
 UserId   INTEGER(9) NOT NULL,
 Name     VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 Usertype   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE application(
 AppNo    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 UserId   INTEGER(9) NOT NULL,
 other    INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model your data in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    UserID   INTEGER(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name     VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    Usertype   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE application
(
    AppNo              VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ApplicantID        INTEGER(9)  NOT NULL REFERENCES user(UserId),
    ApprovingOfficerID INTEGER(9)  NOT NULL REFERENCES user(UserId),
    other              INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Note the [`REFERENCES`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256965/use-of-references-keyword-in-mysql) [foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256965/use-of-references-keyword-in-mysql). They make sure that both `ApplicantID` and `ApprovingOfficerID` are valid `UserID` present in the table `user`.

Set some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO user
    (UserId, Name, UserType)
VALUES
    (  1, 'John Doe', 'user'),
    (100, 'Bob Spongy', 'supervisor') ;

INSERT INTO application
   (AppNo, ApplicantID, ApprovingOfficerID, other)
VALUES
   ('APPX1234', 1, 100, 9999) ;
```

And query joining *twice* to the user table, under two different aliases (`app`, `apr`).

```
SELECT
    a.AppNo, a.ApplicantID, app.Name AS ApplicantName, 
    a.ApprovingOfficerID, apr.Name AS ApprovingOfficerName,
    other
FROM
    application a
    JOIN user app ON app.UserID = a.ApplicantID
    JOIN user apr ON apr.UserID = a.ApprovingOfficerID
```

You'll get

```
AppNo    | ApplicantID | ApplicantName | ApprovingOfficerID | ApprovingOfficerName | other
:------- | ----------: | :------------ | -----------------: | :------------------- | ----:
APPX1234 |           1 | John Doe      |                100 | Bob Spongy           |  9999
```

You can `JOIN` as many tables (or subqueries) as needed when performing a query. If you need to `JOIN` more than once the same table, you need to use an `ALIAS` for each appearance, to be able to distinguish them.

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=089944f047d1506c272adc04dfb133f2)*